# Ask user to login first - web

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web, ionic-framework

I am developing a website in that only two pages are there.

- 1.Login
- 2.Home page

I am using angular framweork.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // Home
    .when("/login", {templateUrl: "partials/login.html", controller: "LoginCtrl",cache:false})
    .when("/newNotification", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "NewNotificationCtrl",cache:false})
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
}]);
```

but when someone is typing website/newNotification without logging in, it is opening that page. How to restrict user to login page only if he directly opens the second page URL ?

Comment: That depends on how your authentication systems works. (It is going to be pretty useless unless the server refuses to serve the secret data if the user isn't logged in though.)

Comment: logging in necessary for a part of home page because i am using username and mail id in home page.when i am directly hitting home page url, it is showing mail and username as null null

Comment: add httpInterceptor and check is user logged in, something to read about http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using ***stateChangeStart***

```
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
                if ( toState.name !== 'login') {
                    $rootScope.token = localStorage.get('user');
                    if ($rootScope.token === null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $rootScope.goTo('login');
                    }
                } else if (toState.name === 'login') {
                    $rootScope.token = localStorage.get('user');
                    if ($rootScope.token !== null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $rootScope.goTo('home');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I believe $stateChangeStart is related to angular ui-router, not $routeProvider and angular-route

Comment: you can also use $routeChangeSuccess for ngRoute 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

Using `localStorage` is my favorite solution. When user **Login**, save `username` and `password` in `localStorage` and redirect to your Homepage. If they **Logout** or close page, you will remove `localStorage` and when load Homepage, you will check `localStorage` items:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("username")!=null && localStorage.getItem("password")!=null){
    driverLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to check that the user is logged in or not before each and every page is opened, and redirecting to the login page if the user is not logged in.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if (!$rootScope.isLoggedIn) {
      // no logged user, redirect to /login
      $location.path("/login");
    }
  }
});
```

In your auth service:

```
app.service('AuthService', function($rootScope, $http) {
  return {
    this.login = function() {
      // Send $http request for login
      $http.post(url, loginData)
        .success(function(res) {
          $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
        })
        .error(function() {
          // Handle request error
        });
    }
  };
});
```